# tomcat freezing nio connectionCount reaching it's limit after few hours of load testing

Tags: connection, tomcat7, nio, performance-testing

Running our application using tomcat 7.0.34 running on windows 2008 r2.
we are Using nio as http connetor (org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocolconnector)
After few hours of load testing (rest requests), connectionCount attribute is being occupied to it's max limit (default 10000). during the run the connection were stable on 5000. The jump for 10000 was in peak.
Although I stopped the load these connections are still showing 10000 and I cannot access the server using http. Tomcat looks like it is freezing ). 
Busythreads and currentThread count shows 37.
Using netstat does not shows these connections. all others server resources are OK (cpu, memory...).
I generated thread dump but it does not indicate on the problem.

Any idea what should be the problem for this server state?

Answer (score 0):

Note that with NIO a current connection does not necessarily mean a thread is allocated to service that request. It could be in keep-alive.

That said, it looks like a bug in the connection count tracking. I don't recall any recent fixes in that area but please retest with 7.0.40. Also please use netstat or similar to confirm that there aren't 10,000 open connections. If you still see the issue please open a bug report at https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla.

It would be extremely helpful if the bug report contained the steps to reproduce this on a clan installation. Anything that resulted in the connection count being non-zero once all requests had finished processing would suffice.